# Image resize with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been searching for some tutorial or something that helps me solve this issue, I'm developing a website where users place ads offering rooms and when they place an ad they have the possibility to add some photos. I want to resize and decrease some quality of the photos  so they won't become to big. The problem is sometimes users insert weird resolutions, so I want to do something like the css background-size: cover property does. Resize photo so the smaller side fit and crop the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Image Moo library will do exactly what you want. Its quite powerful and very easy to use

[Official website](http://www.matmoo.com/digital-dribble/codeigniter/image_moo/)

[CI Forum thread](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/161469/)

Answer (score 0):

Image MOO is a excellent library that can accomplish image manipulations on the fly....

e.g for resizing the uploaded image to a particular path, you just have to do this

```
function example_callback_after_upload($uploader_response,$field_info,                                 $files_to_upload)
{
$this->load->library('image_moo');

//Is only one file uploaded so it ok to use it with $uploader_response[0].
$file_uploaded = $field_info->upload_path.'/'.$uploader_response[0]->name; 

$this->image_moo->load($file_uploaded)->resize(800,600)->save($file_uploaded,true);

return true;
}
```

See this for more details: [image moo library](http://www.matmoo.com/digital-dribble/codeigniter/image_moo/)
 Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
First Load the library of image:

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
```

and then give the config of images like this

```
$config['width'] = 75;
$config['height'] = 50;
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
$this->image_lib->resize();//You can also pass the width,height params through this function
```

That's it.may this helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

**WideImage!**

http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/

http://getsparks.org/packages/wideimage-ci/versions/HEAD/show

**Basic Usage**

```
// output to browser in JPG format with quality set to 80%.
$this->wideimage->load('image.png')->resize(90, 90)->output('jpg', 80);
```

Answer (score -1):

also, test this code.

```
$this->image_moo->load(FCPATH.'/upload/'.$image)->resize(750,450,TRUE)->save(FCPATH.'/upload/'.'750-450-124545cd.png', $overwrite=false);
```

Comment: CPATH gets the full path of the folder ,and load library first $this->load->library('image_moo');